# thinky models in separate files: how to handle cyclical/circular dependencies

Tags: javascript, thinky

I tried to follow the example [here](https://thinky.io/documentation/architecture/), however have no luck with it.

I have User Model in user.js file:

```
import thinky from './thinky';
let type = thinky.type;
let User = thinky.createModel('User', {
  id: type.string(),
  username: type.string(),
});
export default User;

let Game = require('./game');
User.hasAndBelongsToMany(Game, "games", "id", "id");
```

Game Model in game.js file:

```
import thinky from './thinky';
let type = thinky.type;
let Game = thinky.createModel('Game', {
  id: type.string(),
  host: type.string()
});

export default Game;

let User = require('./user');
Game.hasAndBelongsToMany(User, "players", "id", "id");
```

When I try to import them to test.js file, where I create instances of User and Game, I get `First argument of hasAndBelongsToMany must be a Model`

I tried to write it without es6 syntax, still does not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im my example if you change export default to module.exports, everything should work

Answer (score 1):

We need to avoid the circular reference so..

user.js

```
import thinky from './thinky';
let type = thinky.type;
let User = thinky.createModel('User', {
  id: type.string(),
  username: type.string(),
});
export default User;
```

game.js

```
import thinky from './thinky';
let type = thinky.type;
let Game = thinky.createModel('Game', {
  id: type.string(),
  host: type.string()
});

export default Game;
```

index.js

```
import User from './user';
import Game from './game';

Game.hasAndBelongsToMany(User, "players", "id", "id");
User.hasAndBelongsToMany(Game, "games", "id", "id");

export {User, Game};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this loader designed for the very purpose of loading multiple model definitions and making them available to your app.

https://github.com/mwielbut/thinky-loader